# .btn font color not changing

Tags: css, html, button

Beginner to CSS and I'm trying to build a Nav;

So far I have the following CSS code. I want the .btn font color to be white. I've tried using !important; but also not working.

any ideas what is overriding the font color and what I can do to change it?

```
/* navigation */
nav {
  width: 503px;
  height: 45px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  float: right;
  color: #646881;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

nav a:link {
  color: #646881;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #646881
  font-style: italic;
}

nav a:active {
  color: #646881;
}

nav a:visited {
  color: #646881;
}

img.logo{
  max-height: 45px;
  max-width: 105px;
  border-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}


.btn {
background-color: #646881;
width: 75px;
border-radius: 4%;
border: none;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

HTML

Yes, sorry here is the HTML:

```
<header role="header">

</div>
<a href="index.html"><img border="0" class="logo" src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="David Bowie Personas Logo"></a>
<!-- Nav-->
  <nav id="MainMenu" role="navigation">
     <ol>
        <li>
          <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
....
        <li>
          <a href="shop.html" class="btn" role="button">Shop</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: there is no important .. and there is no html

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* navigation */
nav {
  width: 503px;
  height: 45px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  float: right;
  color: #646881;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #646881
  font-style: italic;
}

img.logo{
  max-height: 45px;
  max-width: 105px;
  border-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}


a.btn {
background-color: #646881;
width: 75px;
border-radius: 4%;
border: none;
color: #ffffff;
display: block;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header role="header">
<a href="index.html"><img border="0" class="logo" src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="David Bowie Personas Logo"></a>
<!-- Nav-->
  <nav id="MainMenu" role="navigation">
     <ol>
        <li>
          <a href="about.html" class="btn">About</a>
        </li>
....
        <li>
          <a href="shop.html" class="btn" role="button">Shop</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score -2):

You are referring to an HTML-tag with `nav` i assume that you got a div-element with a class-name, in that case you shall use a dot `.nav`

Comment: hi Victor, Thanks so much! Også dansk så godt at se andre danskere! 
My HTML is a nav element so not using class. Wonder if using class would help with the override?

Comment: Yeah, CSS always uses the most specific argument. Check your .btn and that you have given it a `class` and not a `name`.